# After submit a reply by Ajax Its display a blank data space

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

After submit a reply without 1st post Its display a blank data space and after refresh page its show reply.

What is problem here please.

..............................................................................

This is my script

```
var inputAuthor = $("#author");
var inputComment = $("#comment");
var inputReplycom = $(".replycom");
var inputImg = $("#img");
var inputUrl = $("#url");
var inputTutid = $("#tutid");
var inputparent_id = $("#parent_id");
var replyList = $("#replynext");

function updateReplybox() {
    var tutid = inputTutid.attr("value");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "reply.php",
        data: "action=update&tutid=" + tutid,
        complete: function (data) {
            replyList.append(data.responseText);
            replyList.fadeIn(2000);
        }
    });
}

$(".repfrm").click(function () {
    error.fadeOut();
    if (checkForm()) {
        var author = inputAuthor.attr("value");
        var url = inputUrl.attr("value");
        var img = inputImg.attr("value");
        var replycom = inputReplycom.attr("value");
        var parent_id = inputparent_id.attr("value");
        var tutid = inputTutid.attr("value");

        $('.reply_here').hide();
        $("#loader").fadeIn(400).html('<br><img src="loaders.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;<span class="loading">Loading Update...</span>');
        //send the post to submit.php
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "reply.php",
            data: "action=insert&author=" + author + "&replycom=" + replycom + "&url=" + url + "&img=" + img + "&parent_id=" + parent_id + "&tutid=" + tutid,

            complete: function (data) {
                error.fadeOut();
                $("#loader").hide();
                replyList.append(data.responseText);
                updateReplybox();

                $("#repfrm").each(function () {
                    this.reset();
                });
            }
        });
    } else //alert("Please fill all fields!");
    error_message();
});
```

Comment: How/When are these getting called..?

Comment: I can't understand your word T J sir.

Comment: Edited my above script

Comment: You can refer to me with just TJ, I'm asking, when that function executes - what is `$(".repfrm")` is it a submit button or something..? If so are you preventing the form submission..? It'll be much easier to understand your code if you format it properly...  [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)

Comment: Yes. $(".repfrm") is a submit reply button and I am not preventing the form submission. Thank u.

Comment: Try preventing the normal form submission like `$(".repfrm").click(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); ...})`

Comment: and by the way what is `$("#repfrm").each(function(){this.reset();}); ` supposed to do..? `id` should be unique in an HTML document. `$("#repfrm")` will only select the first element with `id` "repfrm". If you have multiple elments use a class instead of `id`

Comment: $("#repfrm").each(function(){this.reset();}); is reset form. which not work now.

Answer (score 0):

Probably all this code should be inside a $(document).ready({ ... });

To debug: Open chrome inspector and put a brakepoint at this line: var tutid = inputTutid.attr("value"); and check for what is inside inputTutid variable.

Also you can try

inputTutid.val();
instead of 
inputTutid.attr("value");

Comment: inputTutid.attr("value"); is a page number. without this value any post cannot display in this page.